# How to find the list of all emails shared with on Nextcloud

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, nextcloud

My company has been using Nextcloud to host invoices for our customers to view. We have created a folder tree and shared individual folders directly to a customers email via this method:
[image]

This works well but we would like to find a list of all the email addresses that we have shared folders with. It is important to note that none have these have been set up as official users, just given access via the share. Where in the Nextcloud server data tree would I be able to find this? I have searched through the /var/www/nextcloud/data directory but could not find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be stored in the database, table oc_share, column share_with. Mail shares have the column share_type set to 4.